# Moving washing machine from upstairs to the basement

Tags: drain-waste-vent

I have a cabin that is in the mountains.  When we bought the washing machine is upstairs and we would like to relocate it to the basement where the dryer is.  What do we need to pump the water from the washing machine upstairs to the drain pipe?

Comment: Is there a closer sewer pipe in the basement you might be able to connect to, rather than running a pipe to the original first floor drain? If the plumbing runs along the basement ceiling, it might be possible - some washers can pump water 8 feet up. Not a plumber, but I've seen this done before.

Comment: They make *drain pumps* for basement sinks but IDK if those have the ability to keep up with the capacity of a washer discharge. [This one from Granger](https://www.grainger.com/product/1GEK4?ef_id=CjwKCAjwwqaGBhBKEiwAMk-FtFW9wX3TgsDpt5LUzYwBbKXEeswmtA_oq8zH3AkkEk7SvdESRyf6ZBoCC1kQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!496359973801!!!g!472069305098!&gucid=N:N:PS:Paid:GGL:CSM-2295:4P7A1P:20501231&gclid=CjwKCAjwwqaGBhBKEiwAMk-FtFW9wX3TgsDpt5LUzYwBbKXEeswmtA_oq8zH3AkkEk7SvdESRyf6ZBoCC1kQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) claims to but it's also $300.

Comment: I don't believe a washing machine has enough power to pump water upstairs (presumably second story). Are you on a septic system? It sounds like you need to hire a professional to tie your washer into the sewer lines. If you're remote enough then you can probably discharge it directly outside but in general it should discharge above a p-trap.

Comment: @mazura those do work. I suggest that a larger tank is used and that size or smaller pump, it’s a great way to add size to small upstairs bedrooms putting in a laundry chute moving washer and dryer downstairs adding a wash sink and even a grinder toilet like saniflow huge value increase for not much in $ one of the biggest $ per square foot increases we had.+

Answer (score 2):

Normally a small tank is installed many times under a wash basin so you have the basin a small pump to pump up to a gray water or house sewer pipe. The pump is float activated and usually runs off 110v. The small pump takes longer to empty the tank and can work with 1/2 or 3/4 pipe. I believe the tank volume was 7-12 gallons so it was more than the washer held incase the sink was in use, both fill the tank until a mid level then the pump turns on.

By adding the wash sink a the washer and a saniflow toilet about 2k with the plumbing and power we added close to 20k in the house resale because of a larger bedroom, and extra bathroom.

There are small systems for sink only you really want a tank 1.5x the washer capacity if adding a sink. You don’t need a battery backup as the washer won’t run without power and the tank can take a few minutes of use for hand washing while the power is out.

Comment: Install a sink while you're at it, +1. There's your capacity, no problem : discharge into the sink. Then you can put a screen sock on the line and use a screened strainer to prolong the life of the pump.